# Drupal 10.1 Aggregated CSS files Not Cached Due to New Query String

Tags: drupal, http-caching

Since 10.1 an extremely long query string is being added to all aggregated css files.

delta=3&language=en&theme=hhc&include=eJx9UEGSxCAI_JCJb9iXTKFSkRqjFmB28_s12XFS2cNcpKFtaPCF0QZuFdJcuSyMIsaXrPijDdKgrsqUKD_FyC6Kq3UgaGL0dknFQerKqx14pQ3P_yaSaOHdQqU3XoGfE8jECOHsoeASygk3CljMRvgt9nzntYSW8DYgkNQEHo2WkhywfUXTBHl8OvBM3b_8aakvwrkTErFG5NDV7ZA2nkT37na5Krdx3Z7r7AoZFuTPRxpOIKyUH6_sjDJcnqaMxMLqm44eI78r3xplxA_UHMuGfKyY9f9VZhQPFb8OsXG0PCpVtAP8AuL1yiY

These css files are no longer cached.  Every analysis tool I have tried flags this as a warning.  Is this query string required or is there a config option to disable it?  If required, seems like a big step backwards.